# `npm install` behaves differently

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

On my usual OSX workstation, running `npm install` prints out a lot of info to the terminal, such as `npm http request GET http://...` lines.

However on my new OSX workstation, `npm install` simply shows a single line of `fetchMetadata -> ...`

[image]

before displaying a tree containing everything it installed.

**Question:** What may be causing the difference in the output from `npm install`?

In the older system, npm version is `1.1.28` and `npm get progress` gives `undefined`. In the newer system, npm version is `3.8.6` and `npm get progress` is `true`.

Comment: What does each give you when running `node -p "process.stderr.isTTY"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The progress bar was added as a part of [npm v3.0.0](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v3.0.0). Your older OS X Workstation must have been running a version of NPM that was v2.x.x or older.

If you were to run `npm config ls -l` when running npm v2.x.x or older, the `progress` configuration option isn't present. However, when running the same command with npm v3.x.x the `progress` option is present and defaulted to `true`.

Here is an excerpt from the release notes talking about the addition of the progress bar when installing

> #### The Age of Progress (Bars)!
>
> [#6911](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6911) ([#1257](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1257) [#5340](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5340) [#6420](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6420)) The spinner is gone (yay? boo? will you miss it?), and in its place npm has progress bars, so you actually have some sense of how long installs will take. It's provided in Unicode and non-Unicode variants, and Unicode support is automatically detected from your environment.

Answer (score 0):

This is because newer versions of NPM just show this progress bar.